# Terminal freezes after roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! i have a problem.I've written a roslaunch but if execute it and then ctrl-c the current window of the terminal freezes and i have to open a new one.
It's almost equal to others .launch files that do not give problem,except that in this one i passes some args to a node using: args="\dir\blabla.ext"
what could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29910/terminal-freezes-after-roslaunch/) by [ldima](https://answers.ros.org/users/1979/ldima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-03-17**:
Can you post the launch file, what operating system, what version of ROS, etc? Need more info to help ... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIRC, teleop_base_keyboard takes input from the current terminal, so it's likely that its taking over the terminal that you are running roslaunch from.  You should run teleop_base_keyboard separately.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0